# How to use mpirun without any process listening 0.0.0.0

Tags: python, mpi, openmpi

I have to disable the behavior of listening to 0.0.0.0 when I use OpenMPI to run python code parallel in paralell. How should I set the param of mpirun command?

I have tried btl_tcp_if_exclude and NCCL_SOCKET_IFNAME param, but mpi still have a process which listen to 0.0.0.0.

[netstat status shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayCjb.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: select an interface that you know is working, for example (assuming you use Open MPI 4 or lower) `mpirun --mca oob_tcp_if_include eth0 --mca btl_tcp_if_include eth0 ...`